# webRTC - how to handle the situation when caller disconnects call before the callee could 'Allow' media permission

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am facing an issue with local stream(local camera). Here is what happens:

1. Caller offers call.
2. Disconnect button appears for the caller.
3. Permission dialogue(by browser) appears for the CALLEE.
4. CALLER presses Disconnect button and hangup signal is sent to the callee.
5. Callee's client peerconnection etc is cleaned up(reset vars etc)
6. Callee presses 'Allow' in the dialogue that appeared in step 3 above.
7. Local camera(of callee) opens although we don't need it now since the call has been disconnected by the caller. And it closes only after refreshing the page.

Is there a way to close that permission dialogue when callers send 'hangup' signal and the callee cleans up local peer connection and stuff?

If there is any other way to handle this please suggest the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to programatically cancel a getUserMedia request. You can however stop all the tracks in the MediaStream via `stream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop())` once the promise resolves.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That part already happens on receiving the 'hangup' signal. No matter how late callee presses 'Allow', after receiving that signal, the browser turns camera on. It `getUserMedia` awaits for the user's choice(Allow or not).